# Excel VBA / Macro Assistance Required - Hidden Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure that this is a relatively simple query, but to say I'm an amateur with VBA would be a compliment.

What I'm trying to do is use a macro button to copy certain information from one sheet to a mastersheet.  This is working fine, until I hide the rows (there are 880 rows in total and given that these sit alongside data entry tables, I kinda need to hide them to ease navigation).

This is the code that I am presently using - could it be amended so as to include hidden rows?

Thank you in advance,

Rob

```
Private Sub CopyDataTeam1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = ActiveSheet
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("MainData")

    copySheet.Range("AY5:BC5", copySheet.Range("AY5:BC5").End(xlDown)).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheets("MainData").Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "*This is working fine, until I hide the rows*" Uh, OK, *Then* what happens?  Tell us what the problem is, including any error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and apologies for being so vague. Basically, there isn't an error, but I'm expecting 875 rows of data to be copied, but instead, it only copies over the 29 rows which are not hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to check your sheet first for hidden rows. Store that to a Range object.

Unhide your range, do your stuff, then rehide your range...

```
'pass in a worksheet, and get all the hidden rows
Function HiddenRange(ws As Worksheet) As Range

Dim hideRange As Range
Dim column As Long

    'use column a
    column = 1

'if your hidden rows are at the end of your sheet, then 
'.End(xlUp) may not capture the end of the sheet correctly.
'could use UsedRange.Rows instead..
For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row

    If ws.Rows(i).Hidden Then

        If hideRange Is Nothing Then

        Set hideRange = ws.Rows(i)

        Else

        Set hideRange = Application.Union(ws.Rows(i), hideRange)

        End If

    End If

Next i

'return our hidden range
    If hideRange Is Nothing = False Then

    Set HiddenRange = hideRange

    End If

End Function


Public Sub UsageExample()

Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'disable error tracking as we get type mismatch if rng is set to nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = HiddenRange(Sheet1)

'resume error handling
On Error GoTo err


If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Rows.Hidden = False


'do your stuff in here

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Rows.Hidden = True


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

err:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox err.Description, vbExclamation, "An error occured"

End Sub
```

---

You may also want to change the way you set your copy range. Don't use xlDown, as if you have any blank cells in Column BC the range won't be set properly.

Changing it to the below will set the range based on the bottom value in column `BC`

```
copySheet.Range(copySheet.Range("AY5"), copySheet.Range("BC" & copySheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your comment.  This is a dashboard that is intended for use by multiple third parties, so I want the rows to be hidden upon presenting it to them.  Ideally, they populate the tables, the data is transferred into the hidden rows and the macro transfers this hidden data into a master sheet which I then use to populate a pivot chart. Would I be able to determine the hidden rows as a range/s if not continuous?  Thanks, Rob.

Comment: @RobZacher Yes, this will work if the rows are not continuous.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for your assistance with this.  However, the code runs, but continues to copy over only the 29 rows displayed.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again, Rob.

Comment: @RobZacher did you put your code in the part marked `'do your stuff in here` and did you pass your sheet into the function? (not sheet1 like in the usage example). `Set rng = HiddenRange(copySheet)`

Comment: I thought I had - but upon trying again, it's working as intended!  I'm delighted, but I know that VBA (and Excel in general) is a harsh mistress!  I'm going to check a few things out before clicking my heels and yelping 'Yeehah!', but it's looking promising! Feedback will be left accordingly, you've been completely invaluable!